# What's the shortcut to build a project using a MAC + VM?

Tags: visual-studio-mac, amazon-workspaces

I'm using **Mac+ a VM**  and I would like a shortcut equivalent to f5 on a **PC** so that I'm able to speed up my workflow.. Thanks!

1. f5 does nothing (can I map it somehow?)
2. Command + f5 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same keyboard shortcuts as for Visual Studio on Windows, open Preferences - Environment - Key Bindings and select 'Visual Studio (Windows)'.

[image]

Note that F5 Debugs the project.

You can also configure keyboard shortcuts on this page.